# Why are there consecutive and repeated system calls in Android？

Tags: android, linux, system

I'm new to Android. Recently, I'm learning to use strace to track Android system calls. I only save the name of the tracked system calls for subsequent research. However, the problem is that the system calls I extracted with a lot of duplicate items, as shown in the Figure 1. below. Why does it happen that the same system call is repeated many times?

[Figure 1. system calls.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65hbg.png)

Comment: It is impossible to say.  You would need to 1) look at the system call arguments, and 2) look at the application code that corresponds to this sequence of this syscalls.

Comment: *"I only save the name of the tracked system calls for subsequent research."* - Well that was a mistake ... because by only saving the names you have thrown away some of the information that you need to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Without the arguments to the calls, and further details on what the program does, it is next to impossible to venture a guess. Nothing in the image tells if there is some time between calls or if they are back to back.

E.g. `ioctl` is a call to configure a device. Perhaps there are several devices to configure? Several separate configurations to do?

It is normal to do several `read,`write`, and other such I/O calls one after the other.

Look up the calls to see what they do.